# Excel Multiline text truncation

Tags: excel, vba

I have a multiline text in cell of specific column which has numbers in brackets [], in each line

[LINK TO FILE](http://jmp.sh/v/LHA0OYzDw1xqZAQsc5BG)

actual data runs into more than 1000 rows, want to generate result output 1 and 2 in newly inserted column.

i have formula which does the extraction of text written between bracket but it works on only first line not in entire multiline text.

```
=MID(A2,FIND("[",A2)+1,FIND("]",A2)-FIND("[",A2)-1)
```

can any one help me with macro to run on specific column "ABC" and only keep text in bracket.

Comment: It looks to me like all you have to do is keep the text that is left of the first space.

Comment: sorry Jeeped i will try to keep this in mind in future. you are right

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
Sub get_btw_bracket()

    output_row = 1
    input_row = 1
    input_column = 1

    Do Until Sheet1.Cells(1, input_column) = "ABC" Or input_column = 50
        input_column = input_column + 1
    Loop
    If input_column = 50 Then Exit Sub

    Do Until Sheet1.Cells(input_row, input_column) = ""
        cell_data = Sheet1.Cells(input_row, input_column)
        split_by_newline = Split(cell_data, Chr(10))

        For Each element In split_by_newline
            Sheet1.Cells(output_row, 10) = Right(element, Len(element) - InStr(element, "[") + 1)
            output_row = output_row + 1
        Next element
        input_row = input_row + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: my column changes can we find it by header name? and insert next column with data?

Comment: The "1" in "Sheet1.Cells(input_row, 1)" is the location of the column. The "1" means column A, a "2" would point to column B and so on. If you want the column to change, then you need to change the "1" to a variable and set that variable to the column you want to loop through. So, you would need another do until loop that loops through the columns in row 1 and finds your header name.

Comment: unfortunately it does nothing i have updated the screeshot 2 wich column name can you help?

Comment: it seems column name is different

Comment: thanks Charles but can you download file and make code accordingly currently it doesnot help

Answer (score 0):

Enable the macro in your sheet, press `Alt + F11` and select Insert --> Module and paste the below code in the module window,

```
Sub SplitCells()
'Update 20141024
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, 
Type:=8)
For Each Rng In WorkRng
lLFs = VBA.Len(Rng) - VBA.Len(VBA.Replace(Rng, vbLf, ""))
If lLFs > 0 Then
    Rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(lLFs).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
    Rng.Resize(lLFs + 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(VBA.Split(Rng, vbLf))
End If
Next
End Sub
```

save the module, select the range of the column that you want to modify and press F5 in the module. The range is again showed in a dialog box. Press Ok.
Now you will have all the texts in separate rows. You could now use this columns and use the formula to derive the required strings. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you do not want to use macros and want to do this with pure excel, there is a way too. Let me know if you want

Comment: thanks gowtham but solution splits multiline to separate row, I am interested in keeping all content in same cell but remove respective multiline text followed by tab see updated image as result anticipated

Comment: @sapna am not understanding the difference between both the images. Both seems to be similar. please elaborate....

Comment: i have updated the representative excel file with results anticipated via macro

Comment: got it.. so want your output also to be in the same cell just like the input strings?

Comment: yes and in next type output wherein second bunch of text A1 , A2 etc are conconated